# Как сделать условие, при смене числа, лейбл устанавливает текст

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть `label1`, он получает дату. И есть `label2`, он ведет счет. И при использование функций, `label2` увеличивает число (счетчик). Надо, чтоб если меняется `label1` (дата), `label2` (счет) обнулялся.. а точнее ставил `text` - @"0".

Comment: Каким образом label1 меняет дату??
Таким же пусть обнуляет label2.

Comment: с каким-то интевалом? как он это делает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите код, чтобы было о чём говорить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте доступ к дате только через метод, например:

```
void SetDate(DateTime new date){...}
```

И в теле метода обнуляйте счетчик (и меняйте дату).

Comment: можно пожалуйста по подробней?

Answer (score 0):

В том же методе, где устанавливаете новую дату - обнуляйте ваш счетчик.

Comment: у меня парсится системное время при включении программы...  счетчик считает выполненные действия. т.е если я выключу и включу программу, счет не сбрасывается. Надо чтоб была проверка на дату, если дата изменилась, то счетчик label2= @"0
"